# FIDO2 authenticator simulator

Tags: python, fido

I am looking for a Python simulation of a `FIDO2` authenticator(i.e., piece of code that simulates the physical token).

I have not been able to find any implementation with Python. Most of the implementation I found were protocols used in `FIDO` specification, not the simulation of the authenticator itself. Anyone knows a library, opensource program that does that?